# When might you choose to use ViewState over the Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a doubt why we use ViewState because Session can keep its state throughout the application. Then why is the need for ViewState which can keep the state only in a single Page?

Comment: `ViewState` is web forms, not asp.net-mvc!

Comment: Well, one might not *want* the state to be remembered for the entire session. The view state is sent via a hidden field in the page, while the session is taken via cookies. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733482/what-is-the-difference-between-sessionstate-and-viewstate) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

First Thing first is to know what is

**View State**
Is information of a particular page in `webforms`. It is stored in hidden field. It is used to maintain that the page remembers what he did on it the last time.

**Session**
Is information that is related to a specific session.i.e. certain browser

now coming to your question

When to use and not use is a cluster F......

as all have their specific pros and cons specially `ViewSate` is more a con I guess since the MVC was introduced.
One can use `viewstate` to store values to remember  when its page have a post back  as every time, when a page is in a post back stage it removes all the values of user controls .i.e. like `Label` and `TextBox`  in asp.net . So to keep the value you've to`EnableViewState` property to `true` 
Session on the other hand is used when you wish to move from page to page, to keep some specific value for all the pages. For example: one keeps `UserId` in session so he can visit all the page which need some kind of`authorization` or `authentication`

**Update**

As you've changed you question while I was type:
In that case 
Sessions is for specific time whereas  `Viewstate` does not as `Viewstate` is a temporary storage mechanism. `Controls` that use `viewstate` have their `state` rendered into the html page as hidden input.

Hope this will help you in any way, and don't worry about vote down you'll get use to of it

Answer (score 2):

If the user opens several instances of the application in different tabs of the browser, the data stored in Session will be shared by all of them (unless [something special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367189/use-different-session-if-user-logs-in-multiple-times/36367912#36367912) is done to avoid that). One instance modifying a value in a Session variable will overwrite the same variable saved by the other instances, causing a mixup of the data. Using ViewState ensures that each instance is not affected by the others.